# Vector file not found in Metaio cloud plugin viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++, metaio

I have installed a Metaio SDK in my IOS app and currently i am getting an error in the MetaioCloudPluginViewController.h that the vector file is not found, i have tried to change the type from .m or .mm where i have used this sdk file but unfortunately if i would do it then the new errors are popping up such as "comparison between pointer and integer". I have changed few things in my build setting but still the result is same.

This the file which i am including in the stated viewcontroller.

```
#include <vector>
```

The below code is used in one of the viewcontroller.m file.

```
- (IBAction)onStartPushed:(id)sender {
        // Create a new ARViewController. All channel details and properties are defined in that class.
        // see ARViewController.mm for the implementation
        ARViewController* metaioCloudPlugin = [[ARViewController alloc] init];

        // present the viewcontroller
        [self presentViewController:metaioCloudPlugin animated:YES completion:nil];

        // release it, because it's retained as modalViewController
        //[metaioCloudPlugin release];
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename your viewcontroller.m to viewcontroller.mm file because there is a C++ code.

Hope this helps.